# Plugin.LocalNotification how disable notification

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, notifications

I'm having trouble disabling app notifications. I use this method to set the notification:

```
public async void Createnotification(DateTime dt)
    {
        DT = dt;

        string hour = DT.Hour.ToString();
        string minute = DT.Minute.ToString();

        var pref = new Prefs();
        pref.SaveSPrefs("not_hour", hour);
        pref.SaveSPrefs("not_minute", minute);

        string title = AppResources.str_not_title;
        string message = AppResources.str_not_message;

        var notification = new NotificationRequest
        {
            NotificationId = 100,
            Title = title,
            Description = message,
            ReturningData = null, // Returning data when tapped on notification.

            Schedule =
            {
               NotifyTime = DT  //DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5), // Used for Scheduling local notification, if not specified notification will show immediately.
            }
        };
        await LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification);
    }
```

The notifications themselves work fine, but disabling not. I tried to disable them like this:

```
 LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Clear(100); //this not working
 LocalNotificationCenter.Current.ClearAll();    //and this too
```

Please show me what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: When you say “disabling” do you mean cancelling a scheduled notification before it is delivered? I don’t use C# but I did find what I think is the plug-in you are using on GitHub and there is a `Cancel` method on `Current` which takes a notification id. There is also a `Cancel` method on the `NotificationRequst` itself (which just calls the first method with its own id). Maybe that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I mean a notification that has already been created. I've also tried referencing NotificationRequest directly for cancel notification but that doesn't work either. The notification keeps showing up.